# Train to become or train me to become

Tags: verbs, expression-choice

I'm writing a Statement of Purpose for graduate programs in mathematics. I wrote:

> I sincerely hope that I will have the opportunity to join 
>   **(university)** and to train to become a mature mathematician.

Is it better to say **"train to become a mature mathematician"** or **"train me to become a mature mathematician"**? Is there any better expression regarding this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Train is what's different here. In the first instance, train is used to explain what the person speaking is doing. "I will train to become..." versus the second which is said to someone else. "I want you to train me to become..."

Comment: @JaredKauffman Thanks for your comment. And I guess both of them are correct in grammar?

Comment: Yep, however they both have very different uses. Be very careful to make sure to use the right one. If you were asking the teacher to train you to become a mathematician, you'd use the second. Since you are asking to train, you use the first. Glad I could help.

Comment: @JaredKauffman Pretty sure I will use the first one now.

Comment: Why complicate things? *...and train **as a mathematician**.* You've presumably given your age elsewhere in the document, so why bother mentioning ***mature**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure if I use it correctly but I intend to use "mature" to describe "mathematical maturity" rather than my age...

Comment: @user136592: I wouldn't count on that being understood!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for pointing out. I will use "a mathematician".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Train to become" is correct. You would use "Train me to become" in the case of telling someone else they will train you. Since in this instance you want to train, you would say that you want to "train to become".

Answer (score 0):

I would say "train to become" because "train me to become" is and sounds to directly.
Btw "train me to become" sounds quite impolite to me.